# Allow database connections from anywhere?

Tags: mysql, local, external

Currently, my MySQL server's bind-address in the my.cnf config file is set to 127.0.0.1 which works perfectly fine for local connections to any database. However, I need to allow local and external connections. When I set the bind-address to the server's actual IP address, it works for external...but not local.

How can I get both types of connections to work at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Use `0.0.0.0`. It stands for all interfaces.

Comment: Ah, thanks. MySQL issues seem to always have the simplest solutions - can't believe I didn't think of that